# Someone else on my computer at the sametime?

Tags: monitoring

What should I do if I feel that someone else is accessing my computer at the sametime I am using it?  I think about this almost always no matter which carrier I use, or even try a different computer. The computer seems so slow in processing any request whether already downloaded or a new search, accessing my email account or accessing an email sent.  Last night while researching on Google, suddenly the usually slow computer search began going to all these different sites without use of the keyboard.  I just sat back and waited.  I am sick of this.  What can I do?  I am not computer literate at all. Thank-you.

Comment: If what you say about the computer going to different sites by itself is true then disconnect it immediately from the network and read [How to deal with a compromised server](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are a lot of way for secure your computer.
First of all install [antivirus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus_software) and [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) programs to your computer.
Learn [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)/[IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) protocol.When you learn this protocol you can control your network easily.If you feel that someone else is accessing your computer , you can control connections

When you type

```
netstat -n or netstat -ano
```

on the cmd.exe .You can see all active connections.If there is suspicious connection you can block this port on firewall.
Also you can type

```
netstat -b
```

on the cmd.exe .You can see active ports that used by programs.If there is suspicious program you can block this program on firewall.

When you use your computer for online banking or other important functions, you can use on-screen keyboard.

On the other hand, learn physical security.There are some hardware keyloggers for record keystroke.Check cables on your computer , if you are using desktop computer.